# Which major characters lack Aura?

Tags: rwby

Watching *RWBY*, I've noticed that most characters, even the ones who aren't necessarily combat-oriented, have an Aura of some sort.

For instance, Arthur Watts, whom Salem recruited as a hacker who was never supposed to get in a fight, has a substantial Aura, able to take many otherwise lethal hits, albeit a fairly weak one by the standards of Huntresses and Huntsmen to judge by how many tricks he needed to stand up to Ironwood.  Robyn Hill, a prospective council member who doesn't seem to have been a vigilante at first, also does. Pietro, who's a scientist, has a substantial Aura, as do a variety of criminals and ne'er-do-wells like Neopolitan.

But the impression I always got was that most people didn't have Aura, or at least not one that was good for much of anything. Given the theme of the show, there's an obvious bias toward people with a talent for fighting, which means an Aura and even a Semblance. But do any major (or fairly major) characters simply not have any Aura to speak of? Obviously, this excludes characters like Ozpin and Salem who may not have Aura but do have something a little extra.

Comment: Foiled again by the non-standard spellings. Robyn, Qrow... I am honestly surprised it's not Seilum instead of Salem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Aura in RWBY is not entirely consistent through the show. In Volumes 1-3 the rules are not fully established and it is guided more by the rule of cool to let the characters being able to tank more damage. From Volume 4 it is visual better represented and has more consistent power scaling. The basic concept however hasn't changed.

Everyone with a soul has Aura. A basic introduction into the concept was given in the fourth episode of the supplementary series "RWBY: World of Remnant" (Remnant is the name of the world in RWBY), which was released on the RWBY Volume 2 DVD and later on [youtube](https://youtu.be/SsAG3QHAu5w). A transcript is available [on the rwby fandom wiki](https://rwby.fandom.com/wiki/Aura_(WoR_episode)). It is explained that

> Aura is a manifestation of the soul, a life force that runs through every living creature on Remnant, whether they are a meager shopkeep or a renowned knight. However, what sets true warriors apart from all others is their ability to amplify and control their Aura. Aura is primarily used as a defensive mechanism. Passively coating the wielder in a protective force field, it can protect a combatant from what would normally be a fatal blow. It does not, however, make the user invincible.

So the main "practical purpose" of Aura is defence. Another introduction into the concept is given in Episode 6 of Volume 1 ("The Emerald Forest"). Pyrrha explains:

> With practice, our Aura can be our shield. Everyone has it, even animals.

She goes on to "unlock" Jaune's Aura.

This is picked up again in Episode 4, Volume 5 ("Lighting the Fire"). Oscar and Ruby are training hand-to-hand combat and after Oscar is knocked down by Ruby, Ozpin (in Oscars mind) says:

> You forgot to engage your Aura, again.

Shortly after Ren explains to Oscar:

> Your body isn't used to this kind of training, not to mention generating a defensive Aura on your own. It takes intense concentration at first, but in time it will become second nature, allowing you to deflect attacks and gradually heal your wounds.

So even when someone has unlocked their aura and knows how to use Aura defensively, it needs actively be engaged. However, we as viewers have usually have no indication that Aura is engaged except when someone takes a heavy blow or Aura is exhausted and the Aura is flickering.

Since Semblance is Aura in a more tangible form, we know everyone with a Semblance has unlocked and trained Aura. The three most prominent characters that don't have a Semblance are Mercury, Watts and Torchwick. Mercury's Aura breaks in the fight vs. Yang (Episode 6, Volume 3, "Fall") and Watt's Aura saves him from a bullet in his fight vs. Ironwood (Episode 11, Volume 7, "Gravity"). We have never seen Torchwick's Aura break or flicker, but his fights in Volumes 1-2 happened prior to the introduction of visual clues for Aura breaking. Only his last fight, in which he was swallowed whole, happened after the introduction of those visual clues. I would assume that he uses Aura: in his fight with Blake in Episode 11, Volume 2, "No Brakes" he takes several sword hits mid-air without injury and continues to fight after. Furthermore it was stated by the RWBY creators that he originally was going to have a Semblance, but they never had the chance to include it (Director's Commentary Volume 7, Episode 7).

If you consider the likes of Jacques Schnee as a main character, then "non-warrior" characters like him are your best bet for someone not being able to use their Aura, it is never explicitly stated however.

Comment: "...or at least not one that was good for much of anything." In theory, everyone has Aura, but it need not be capable of anything particularly supernatural. That is what I am asking about.

Comment: Sorry can you rephrase? Aren't you asking if any major characters lacks Aura?

Comment: I am asking whether any major character lacks Aura for practical purposes. We see that there are many nameless side characters that easily die to one swipe of a Grimm's claw, so their Aura does not grant them any appreciable supernatural durability or strength. Do any of the main characters fall into this category?

Comment: I expanded the answer. AFAIK it was never stated that a character lacks Aura "for practical purposes". Note that Sienna Khan was stabbed to death in one hit, but was otherwise a formidable fighter and according to the conical game RWBY Amidity Arena had also a Semblance. So just knowing how to use Aura, is not saving you from unexpected attacks.

Answer (score 3):

> the impression I always got was that most people didn't have Aura

Most people probably don't have a *Semblance*, but almost everyone should have an *Aura*. The very first time we hear of Aura, Pyrrha describes it thusly:

> Aura is the manifestation of our souls. It bears our burden and shields our hearts.

The way I've always read it is that everyone with a soul has an Aura, even if for most common (non-Hunter, non-fighter etc) folks it's probably not a lot of it. That's why Penny is special: she has Aura without having a soul.

As you noticed, most fighter-types have lots of Aura. I may be proven wrong, but given that a good bunch of the major characters fall into that category, and have a soul to begin with, I doubt any of them would not have Aura.

Comment: That's part of why I mentioned "no Aura to speak of". instead of "no aura".  Also, the full line was "the impression I always got was that most people didn't have Aura, or at least one that was good for much of anything". Sure, everyone has at least a bit, but almost every major character, even those who aren't fighters, seems to have a substantial amount. Are there any exceptions?

Comment: @Adamant aren't we going in circles there? It's not easy to prove a negative, but what this answers boils down to is "probably not, here's the evidence why". (I agree it would have been more interesting to provide an exception, though, but I doubt there's one)

Comment: Well, that's the question. Is there one? A clear sign of having next to no Aura would be dying in one hit without previous exhaustion, as some regular soldiers do from Grimm.